# Single Value Decomposition algorithm not working

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, svd

I wrote the following function to perform SVD according to page 45 of 'the deep learning book' by Ian Goodfellow and co.

```
def SVD(A): 

    #A^T
    AT = np.transpose(A)

    #AA^T
    AAT = A.dot(AT)

    #A^TA
    ATA = AT.dot(A)

    #Left single values
    LSV = np.linalg.eig(AAT)[1]
    U = LSV #some values of U have the wrong sign 

    #Right single values
    RSV = np.linalg.eig(ATA)[1]
    V = RSV
    V[:,0] = V[:,0] #V isnt arranged properly

    values = np.sqrt(np.linalg.eig(ata)[0])

    #descending order
    values = np.sort(values)[::-1]

    rows = A.shape[0]
    columns = A.shape[1]

    D = np.zeros((rows,columns))

    np.fill_diagonal(D,values)


    return U, D, V
```

However for any given matrix the results are not the same as using

```
np.linalg.svd(A)
```

and I have no idea why.

I tested my algorithm by saying

```
abs(UDV^T - A) < 0.0001
```

to check if it decomposed properly and it hasn't. The problem seems to lie with the V and U components but I can't see what's going wrong. D seems to be correct.

If anyone can see the problem it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: Sorry. Figured since SVD is used in PCA and as a tool in many ML applications it was relevant. It's in nearly every ML book

Comment: It's true, but the fact that you may need help debugging a sorting algorithm which will be subsequently used, say, in a spaceship, does not qualify the question as being about `space-engineering`... SVD is being used in myriad other fields beyond ML

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with the order of the eigenpairs that eig(ATA) and eig(AAT) return. The documentation of np.linalg.eig tells that no order is guaranteed. Replacing eig by eigh, which returns the eigenpairs in ascending order, should help. Also don't rearrange the values.

By the way, eigh is specific for symmetric matrices, such as the ones that you are passing, and will not return complex numbers if the original matrix is real.